# Conditionals for EL/SUSE affecting all distributions

Tags: rpm-spec

I have a spec file for FFmpeg which targets EL, Fedora, Mageia and SUSE. Because of the versions of NASM available for the older EL/SUSE distributions, my spec file is supposed to selectively disable ASM for distributions that do not have a new enough NASM version available.

```
./configure --prefix="%_prefix" --libdir="%_libdir" --shlibdir="%_libdir" --incdir="%_includedir/ffmpeg" --extra-cflags="%optflags" --optflags="%optflags" --enable-pic --disable-stripping --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
%if 0%{?el5}%{?el6} || 0%{?suse_version} < 1315
--disable-yasm /
%endif
--disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avformat --disable-swresample --disable-swscale --disable-postproc --disable-avfilter
```

problem is, ASM is being disabled on every distribution, including SUSE versions newer than 1315. How can I make the conditionals only affect the distributions that they're supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./configure --prefix="%_prefix" --libdir="%_libdir" --shlibdir="%_libdir" --incdir="%_includedir/ffmpeg" --extra-cflags="%optflags" --optflags="%optflags" --enable-pic --disable-stripping --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
%if 0%{?el5}%{?el6} || 0%{?suse_version} && (0%{?suse_version} == 0 || 0%{?suse_version} < 1315)
--disable-yasm \
%endif
--disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avformat --disable-swresample --disable-swscale --disable-postproc --disable-avfilter
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, it does a simple *string* comparison, not numerical, and the string `0 < 1` is always true.

Try guarding it with:

```
%{?suse_version}0 < 13150
```

or

```
0%{?suse_version} < 01315
```

instead.